# Can Hawk Moth akumatize Miraculous holders while they’re transformed?

Tags: miraculous-ladybug

We know that *Marinette* and *Adrien* could theoretically be akumatized, but that it would be [unlikely because of their respective personalities.](https://twitter.com/Ladybug_Cartoon/status/780024002706305024) This likely explains why Marinette has not been akumatized, despite Hawk Moth apparently focusing his efforts around her school. For Adrien, likely

> Hawk Moth would not want to akumatize his own son if he could help it.

However, could they be akumatized *while* transformed (assuming they were in the proper mental state)? That  is, could *Ladybug or Cat Noir* be akumatized? It seems as if this might be a good strategy for Hawk Moth to use, if it were possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes

In "Queen Wasp", Hawk Moth akumatizes Chloe Bourgeois into the title character, while Chloe is still transformed into Queen Bee. He seemed to think this would make her particularly powerful, and indeed it seemed to magnify her Queen Wasp powers.

That said, Hawk Moth suggested that this would be a rare opportunity, suggesting that he sees little likelihood of getting the other Miraculous Holders in the right state to be akumatized (he'd also have to get the akuma to touch them).

The fact that Hawk Moth didn't akumatize himself suggests either that the Butterfly Miraculous holder can't akumatize themselves, or more likely that he didn't want to risk Ladybug and Cat Noir to either take it from the Collector or realizing from its presence who he was, since avoiding suspicion was the whole point.

Comment: Your last paragraph needs a little work. I think I know what you're trying to say, but Hawk Moth certainly did akumatize himself, just not while transformed.

Answer (score 3):

**No**

Based on the events of "The Collector" (S2E1), Hawk Moth had to de-transform in order to akumatize himself. As such, this suggests that a Miraculous hero can't be akumatised in their transformed state.

Of course, it also suggests they can be akumatized in their civilian state though.

Answer (score 1):

I am no authority, other than having watched all the episodes about a billion times (with my daughter).

**There is, as yet, no evidence either way.**

I would opine, however, *no*.

What follows is technically an answer to another question, but I think it applies here: Getting akumatized is more than just a personality issue.

There definitely seems to be a great deal of pressure or control exerted over someone’s mind that comes from increasing the dark feelings of doubt, anger, and fear to the point that the targeted individual finds it near impossible to refuse HawkMoth’s “bargain”. We have seen it often enough with people who already knew better and should have recognized the signs (like Alya) or didn't have it in their personality to be cruel or unjust to begin with (like Miléne’s father and Officer Roger) but were just as easily swayed when targeted.

Alternately, getting transformed by a Miraculous amplifies positive and can-do feelings, as evidenced by Marinette’s behavior particularly: When transformed, she had a very can-do attitude, at least to the point of being able to choose to act over run; but when not transformed her doubts and fears controlled her.

This, again, is only an opinion, and could be wrong. As it is in the show, there is no solid evidence either way.

Comment: I know that this is my own question, but upon looking into things further, I have a further piece of information for this answer (if you’d like to add it). Before getting akumatized, a certain someone does  a certain something in Season 2, which might indicate that an active Miraculous gets in the way.

Comment: Alas, I am in the US, and Season 2 has not yet premiered here. :-(
(Feel free to edit the information in, if you wish.)

Answer (score 0):

Marinette and Adrien can be Akumatised. Adrien got Akumatised in *Cat Blanc*, where the owner of the Rabbit Miraculous took Marinette to the future to save him; in case you dont know they revealed identities and fell in love, but then Gabriel stopped letting them stay together.

He revealed his identity to Gabriel by transforming and using Cataclysm to defeat the Akuma that was feeding off Marinette's sadness for her love being taken away from her. Cat Noir got Akumatised too. Cat Noir: 1, Marinette: 0.

Then he turned into Scarlet Moth again in a different episode, and Akumatised Marinette and maybe Cat Noir if my memory is well. Cat has been Akumatised twice probs, and Ladybug once.

But hey, I'm just a Pheasant, what could I possibly know?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Note that the question wasn't about Marinette and Adrien being akumatized, it was specifically about Ladybug and Cat Noir (or any other holder of a miraculous _when transformed_).  You mention Cat Noir being akumatized twice, and Ladybug once, but you need to provide references (e.g. episode and some plot details) to make this a good answer.